# How to get the url of the current view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Currently in a razor view I'm doing:

```
var request = Url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request;
var builder = new UriBuilder(request.Scheme, request.Host.Host, request.Host.Port.Value, request.Path, request.QueryString.Value);
```

A problem with the above is that the port and query string might not be available.

Is there a better and shorter way to get the view's url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only the full URL, you can use these two Extension methods

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions


string fullUrl1 = Request.GetDisplayUrl();
 //or
string fullUrl2 = Request.GetEncodedUrl();
```